# Can't see suggestions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

Im having a problem with Eclipse. When error in code, I can't see suggestions in how to fix the error. The box that has this information is visible, not the text it self.

How can i fix this?

[image: Picture shows problem]

Comment: White text on white background? Have you checked the editor settings?

Comment: Where do I do that?

Comment: I don't know I don't use Eclipse. Check the editor settings.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse on the menubar go to:

*Window* > *Preferences* > *General* > *Appearance* > *Colors and Fonts*

Now select ***Content Assist foreground color*** in the list and click edit.

Select the color you want and that should fix your problem.

In the *Appearance* menu you can also reset your entire theme to fix any other issues with the button ***Restore Defaults***.